# How can i access the currently visible fragment without view pager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I saw various answers on SO but all of them use viewpager to get either the position or the instance of the fragment which is currently visible.

My frame layout only includes two fragments and both of them include recyclerview that's why i didn't implement viewpager there.

But now how can i get the currently visible fragment?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your problem. But you can declare 2 variables refer to your 2 fragments and check if isVisible() returns true. It's easy to do like this because you only have 2 fragments.